# Angular 4/5 > httpclientmodule .get() chaining functions and return-data types

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise, angular5

Please see both answers. (Thanks JLRishe and AngularInDepth.com)

AngularInDepth had also added interesting link to interceptors and HttpClient mechanics in his post:

https://blog.angularindepth.com/insiders-guide-into-interceptors-and-httpclient-mechanics-in-angular-103fbdb397bf

---

Using RxJS and HttpClientModule, When calling `.get()` of `HttpClient` what are the return values in this chain?

```
constructor (private _http: HttpClient) {
...
this._http.get(url).map(res=>res.json()).toPromise()   // how does this chaining work?
```

As I understand, `_http.get(url)` returns an observable, but we are chaining a `.map()` to `.get()` method.

I am also guessing that the following `.map()` work as receiving http-response object, which we promptly converted to json object. Finally, the whole observable is converted to promise with `.toPromise()` which doesn't seem to care whatever `.map()` is doing to the `.get()`

1. So far I understand that `_http.get()` returns an observable and will also provide http-response object (as next or callback function)
2. is .map() function acting just on the response object and will not change the return type of the whole `_http.get()` function. (return type remains the same as observable)? Is my assumption correct?
3. In general, if the above is true, how does JS figure out what kind of chaining function would work on the callback data and which would work on the return type? How do we implement my own custom function so that my chain function would strictly work on the callback data (correct me if I am using the right term) OR the return type?
4. Can we add `.map()` to all async functions (promise,observables,callbacks) to work on their callback data? Likewise, does `.toPromise()` work on all async function to convert them to promises?

Comment: for the `.map`, are you using `Rx/rxjs`?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing it out. Added to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. So far I understand that _http.get() returns an observable and will also provide http-response object (as next or callback function)

`_http.get()` returns an observable *of* http-response objects. You can think of an observable as a window on a stream of values, and in this case that stream would be just a single value (the result)

> 2. is .map() function acting just on the response object and will not change the return type of the whole _http.get() function.

Yes. It creates a *new* observable in which the values from the original observable have been transformed in some way. In this case, that transformation is `res => res.json()`.

> 3. In general, if the above is true, how does JS figure out what kind of chaining function would work on the callback data and which would work on the return type? How do we implement my own custom function so that my chain function would strictly work on the callback data (correct me if I am using the right term) OR the return type?

I don't really understand this question. The function passed to `map` needs to take the observable's contained type as input, and produce some type as output.

> 4. Can we add .map() to all async functions (promise,observables,callbacks) to work on their callback data? Likewise, does .toPromise() work on all async function to convert them to promises?

You can use `.map()` on any observable and you can use `.toPromise()` on any observable. Bear in mind that `.toPromise()` creates a promises for the *first* value that comes out of the observable, so it's typically suited for observables that produce a single value (as this one does).

Comment: for (3) I am questioning Javascript mechanism for return types. For some reasons I was thinking javascript could somehow magically work on the callback data without touching the returned observable. But as you had explained above, it is now clear that `.map()` is making modification to callback data and creating a brand-new observable.

Comment: Also, what is the proper term for response in `_http.get(url).map(response=>response.json())` ? Can we just call it "callback data" ?  It doesnt seem very insightful besides saying it will be in callback.

Comment: @theMobDog You could call it the "result value".

Answer (score 1):

> So far I understand that _http.get() returns an observable and will
>   also provide http-response object (as next or callback function

The signature for the `request` method (which is what is called by `get` internally) is :

```
request(...): Observable<any>
```

which means that it returns an observable that emits items of type `any`. One of the values it returns is `HttpResponse`. However, depending on the `observe` parameter it can return text as in `response.body` or parsed JSON as in `JSON.parse(response.body)`.

> is .map() function acting just on the response object and will not
>   change the return type of the whole _http.get() function. (return type
>   remains the same as observable)? Is my assumption correct?

`map` operates on the values emitted by the observable. And the function signature doesn't explicitly specify these types and instead uses a generic type `any`.

> Can we add .map() to all async functions
>   (promise,observables,callbacks)

Here `map` is specific to the [RxJs library](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map). It's not `map` from the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

> In general, if the above is true, how does JS figure out what kind of
>   chaining function would work on the callback data and which would work
>   on the return type?

You need to read about RxJs operators and lettable operators [here](http://RxJS:%20Understanding%20Lettable%20Operators). RxJs will execute each operator one after the other. All operators work on the data emitted by an observable, in the case of HttpClient it's either `HttpResponse`, `response.body` or `JSON`.

You can read more about how observable chain works in `HttpClient` in the article:

- [Insider’s guide into interceptors and HttpClient mechanics in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/insiders-guide-into-interceptors-and-httpclient-mechanics-in-angular-103fbdb397bf)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. the lettable operators things is new to me and looks 
 like a very useful tool